# TO solve error "Fatal exception

Tags: android, maps, nullpointerexception, location, fatal-error

I am making android application in which i need  user current location by using location manager api... first it ensure internet connectitvity and if internet is not connected there will be dailog box show on app.then it will get langitude and latitude.but when i run this it show shows diferent type of error like fatal main exception etc..i tired hard but seriuosy i couldnot find the way out as it is related to final year project so plz help me..

```
package com.example.directory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    GPSTracker gps;
    ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        //isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        /*if (!isInternetPresent) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }
        else{alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                " working Internet connection", false);}*/
        gps = new GPSTracker(this);
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            Log.d("Your Location", "latitude:" + gps.getLatitude() + ", longitude: " + gps.getLongitude());
        } else {
            // Can't get user's current location
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "GPS Status",
                    "Couldn't get location information. Please enable GPS",
                    false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }
    //  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
/////////////////////
package com.example.directory;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
        this._context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Checking for all possible internet providers
     * **/
    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null)
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null)
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
}


//////////////////
package com.example.directory;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location = null; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
     * app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * 
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }}
/////////////////////////
package com.example.directory;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class AlertDialogManager {
    /**
     * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
     * @param context - application context
     * @param title - alert dialog title
     * @param message - alert message
     * @param status - success/failure (used to set icon)
     *               - pass null if you don't want icon
     * */
    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
            Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if(status != null)
            // Setting alert dialog icon
            alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}

log cat
////////////////////////////
01-26 20:11:59.212: W/dalvikvm(2541): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.directory/com.example.directory.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10042 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10042 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getAllNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:390)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:267)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at com.example.directory.ConnectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet(ConnectionDetector.java:22)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at com.example.directory.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-26 20:11:59.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2541):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Always post a full stack trace for crashing errors.

Comment: Spend some time learning how to debug your application. It's an essential skill for all programmers regardless of programming language. This would allow you to debug and determine the cause of your null pointer very easily and save you lots of time in the end.

Comment: post your full logcat

Comment: @GabeSechan full stack trace mean show logcat?

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10042 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
```

This exception tells you that a permission is missing in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```